# what is the meaning of "expressive" after noun in context?

Tags: word-usage, translation

I can't translate this sentence into my native language.

> The emperors and scholar-officials cannot be reached now, but they have left a wealth of evidence that they found their state sacrifices and music expressive.

*Expressive* is an adjective and it has been placed at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a way to express the construct *find [object] [complement]*, which means *experience or regard something in a specific way*. It has a similar meaning as in the following sentence.

> Both men **found it difficult** to put ideas into words.

In the sentence you quoted, the object is *their state sacrifices and music*, while *expressive* is the complement. It means they regard their state sacrifices and music as expressive.